# Attaching xml files into unit test

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, wcf, unit-testing

On Unit Test project, we use xml files and they are called on the unittest.cs as follows. The xml files are just in the project. If I put the xml files into one folder, then please suggest me the path of the xml that would be written on my unit test.

Now xml files are read like this

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Unit Test 
    /// </summary>
    [DeploymentItem("ProjectName\\UniTest.xml"),
     DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML",
     "|DataDirectory|\\UniTest.xml", "UniTest",
     DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod()]
     public void UniTest() 
     {
       .....

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source code you have posted it seems that you are using MSTest (you should have specified thta in your question). In MSTest you could get the current working directory in which the test executes using the `TestContext` property:

```
public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
```

and then to get the location use the [`DeploymentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.deploymentdirectory.aspx) property:

```
string file = Path.Combine(TestContext.DeploymentDirectory, "ProjectName", "UnitTest.xml");
```

Comment: now it is ProjectName\\UniTest.xml.If I move the xml files into a folder, then is it enough to ProjectName\\folder\\UniTest.xml.but its not working ?

Comment: The file should be part of the unit test project. It could be in a subfolder if you want. The `TestContext.DeploymentDirectory` will give you the base folder of the unit test execution. Explore it and see where is your file stored relatively to it. Then `Path.Combine` to construct the full location.